# Clamav gui for Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: apt, clamav

I have read that Clamav has a GUI.  Does anyone know where i can get Clamav with a GUI? I am running Ubuntu 20.10
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

ClamTk is a graphical front-end for the ClamAV terminal program. To install it in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install clamtk
```

You can also take a look at the Gnome/Nautilus extension *clamtk-gnome* - GNOME (Nautilus) MenuProvider extension for ClamTk. This package contains a nautilus plugin to allow right-click support for easy virus scanning with ClamTk and thus ClamAV in GNOME. To install it in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install clamtk-gnome
```