# Set up ClamAV for email

Tags: email, antivirus, clamav

I have set up ClamAV on Ubuntu on a  single laptop, I am a beginner/ intermediate user and worked my way through the commands and set up the GUI interface. It removed 17 viruses.
I looked at setting up the antivirus for email but there is no GUI for this. I must confess I am somewhat fazed by the ClamAV terminal commands for emails. I have a domain name which has about 5 emails; i.e, name1@XYZ.com name2@xyz.com, name3@xyz.com using Thunderbird.
Plus about 6 or 7 'single' emails such as a gmail address, a yahoo address. These are for different businesses.
Also the commands assume that Clam AV is not installed.
Firstly, am I correct in assuming that the standard installation of ClamAV still needs a further email installation?
I apologise for my ignorance but wonder if some kind experienced user could guide me through this or better still tweak the existing code for my requirements. Hopefully this is the right forum?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314162/clamav-gui-for-ubuntu-20-10